# Javascript doesn't return the value

Tags: javascript, return

I'm trying to write a simple function (checkCard) which checks if the random card created by another function is already in use or not. Here's the place the call is made from:

```
var uC;
// some code including creating the random card
checkCard(card, pCards, dCards, uC);
// uC becomes unidentified here
```

And here's the checkCard itself:

```
function checkCard(card, pCards, dCards, uC) {
    var tCards = pCards.concat(dCards), // an array containing all cards which are in use already
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < tCards.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (card.suit === tCards[i].suit && card.type === tCards[i].type) {
            uC = true; // card is in use already
            break;
        } else {
            uC = false; // card is not in use
        }
    }
    // it still works here: uC is either true or false
    return uC;
}
```

}

Somehow it just doesn't work: checkCard correctly calculates uC and it holds the value "true" or "false" just before the "return uC". But after returning back to the original function uC becomes "unidentified". What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't appear to be assigning the return value to anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not modifying the variable uC passed into the function, but instead a local copy of it. You would have to capture uC from the return:

```
uC = checkCard(card, pCards, dCards);
```

Since you are returning the variable, you do not need to pass it in as a parameter, and you would then create the local variable in the function instead.

```
function checkCard(card, pCards, dCards) {
   var uC;
   ....}
```

Comment: If you don't pass it in as a parameter, you don't have to return it.

Comment: @Grim... expanded my answer

Comment: Sure - but if you didn't declare it, it would remain a global and the original code would work (without the need to return the `uC` variable or send it).

Comment: @Grim... yup - that's another option. I wanted to focus more on why the parameter uC wouldn't modify the original variable (not a pointer)

Answer (score 0):

In the original code, you need

```
uC = checkCard(card, pCards, dCards, uC);
```

Either that, or don't pass `uC` in the function call - if you leave it off it will continue to be a global variable, whereas the way you've done it `uC` in the function is a local variable.

Comment: and you don't need to pass `uC` as a parameter

Comment: Isn't it *or* you don't need to pass uC as a parameter? If the OP didn't do that then uC would be a global. I should put that into my answer.

Comment: You don't - it will pick up the global `uC` variable.

Comment: i mean.. you don't explicitly need to.. but you have to, no body wants to have global variables (like this one) laying around in the app.